# 64Bit Edition for Netbeans and Glassfish

Tags: netbeans, 64-bit, glassfish

Why Netbeans or Glassfish doesn't have 64bit Edition Version to improve performance?
Of course these both applications use JDK 64bit but why there is no any 64bit edition for improving their internal processing?

I think eclipse published in both 32 and 64 bit, isn't?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why Netbeans or Glassfish doesn't have 64bit Edition Version to improve performance?

Because unlike Eclipse, NetBeans and GlassFish aren't platform dependent. So just configure NetBeans or GlassFish to use your 64-bit JVM.

By the way, are you sure you would get [better performances](http://blog.juma.me.uk/2008/10/14/32-bit-or-64-bit-jvm-how-about-a-hybrid/)?

#### Resources

- GlassFish

  - [Thread: how to configure glassfish to use 64 bit jvm](http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?messageID=288897)
  - [GlassFish Wiki: Faq64bitConfig](http://wiki.glassfish.java.net/Wiki.jsp?page=Faq64bitConfig)
  - [64-bit GlassFish, howto, wiki](http://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/64_bit_glassfish_howto_wiki)
- Netbeans

  - [FaqInstall64Bit](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqInstall64Bit)

Comment: There have been some dll's included with NB for a number of releases.

Most of them look like they are used to support profiling, some kind of feature for mobile development, Ruby support and browsing.

Comment: Thanks Pascal, your answer was useful

Comment: Which of these two IDE (eclipse / Netbeans) is more professional?

Answer (score 2):

In the past, GlassFish leveraged some native libraries.

It looks like GlassFish Server 3.1 does not leverage any native libraries, so there is really no need to have a '64 bit' release.

The server will use the jdk that you tell it to use.  If you start the server with the 64-bit JDK, you have a 64-bit 'release'.

The status of NB is similar.  There are some native libraries that ship with NB 6.9, but most of them are far from the 'core' functionality of the IDE.  Shipping a 64-bit edition of NB would not yield much, if any, of a performance boost.

Eclipse may have more of a dependency on native libraries (due to things like SWT) than NB.

Comment: Is this native part new in NB 6.9? I was convinced NB was 100% Java so far. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which of these two IDE (eclipse / Netbeans) is more professional?

Comment: @Navid that is a different and subjective question... you probably need to answer that for yourself.